# Arango ORM to Pydantic

Tags: python, arangodb, pydantic

I'm transferring my code from arango-orm to pydantic. My question is how to write the collection, graph, edge, relation classes in pydantic.

Please guide.
Thank you.

I also tried to install `arangodantic` which results in error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtwdR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [TMalik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20869023/tmalik),

I understand you're looking for a Pydantic-based ArangoDB ORM as an alternative to `arangodantic`, which you encountered issues with. I had a similar requirement in my project where I needed an **async Pydantic**-based **ArangoDB ORM** that could integrate seamlessly with **FastAPI**.

After researching and finding limitations in existing solutions like:

- [arango-orm](https://github.com/threatify/arango-orm) (based on marshmellow)
- [arangodantic](https://github.com/ioxiocom/arangodantic) (not so SQLAlchemy like)
- [aromatic](https://github.com/ronniebasak/aromatic) (not maintained/production ready)

I developed [PydangORM](https://nadobando.github.io/pydangorm). This framework is designed to provide a more intuitive and SQLAlchemy-like experience for handling collections, graphs, edges, and relationships in ArangoDB, all while leveraging the benefits of Pydantic.

PydangORM is currently based on Pydantic V1, and I'm planning to upgrade it to V2 shortly. Here's how PydangORM simplifies working with ArangoDB using Pydantic models:

### **Defining Models**

With `pydangorm`, you can easily define vertex and edge models:

```py
from typing import Annotated
import datetime
from pydango.indexes import PersistentIndex

from pydango import (
    VertexModel,
    EdgeModel,
    EdgeCollectionConfig,
    VertexCollectionConfig,
    Relation,
)


class Visited(EdgeModel):
    rating: int
    on_date: datetime.date

    class Collection(EdgeCollectionConfig):
        name = "visited"
        indexes = [
            PersistentIndex(fields=["rating"]),
        ]


class LivesIn(EdgeModel):
    since: datetime.datetime

    class Collection(EdgeCollectionConfig):
        name = "lives_in"


class City(VertexModel):
    name: str
    population: int

    class Collection(VertexCollectionConfig):
        name = "cities"
        indexes = [PersistentIndex(fields=["name"])]


class Person(VertexModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    lives_in: Annotated[City, Relation[LivesIn]]
    visited: Annotated[list[City], Relation[Visited]]

    class Collection(VertexCollectionConfig):
        name = "people"
        indexes = [
            PersistentIndex(fields=["name"]),
            PersistentIndex(fields=["age"]),
        ]
```

### **CRUD Operations**

Perform basic CRUD operations using the models:

```py
# Create a new person
async def async_application():
    person = Person(name="Alice", age=30)
    person.lives_in = City(name="Buenos Aires", population=16_500_000)
    person.visited = [City(name="San Francisco", population=800_000)]
    person.edges.lives_in = LivesIn(since=datetime.datetime.now())
    person.edges.visited = [Visited(rating=5, on_date=datetime.date.today())]

    await session.save(person)

    # Read a person by their ID
    retrieved_person = await session.get(Person, person.id)

    # Update the person's age
    person.age = 31
    await session.save(person)
```

### **Running Queries**

#### Simple Query

Construct and execute a simple query to retrieve all people over the age of 25:

```py
from pydango.orm import for_

query = for_(Person).filter(Person.age > 25).return_(Person)
people_over_25 = await session.execute(query)
```

#### Traversal Query

Construct and execute a simple query to cities visited by people who visited the same cities of a person:

```py
from pydango.orm import traverse
from pydango import TraversalDirection

person_visited_cities = traverse(
    Person,
    edges=[Person.visited],
    start=person.id,
    depth=(1, 2),
    direction=TraversalDirection.INBOUND,
).return_(Person)
```

I'd be delighted if you give PydangORM a try for your project. Your feedback would be invaluable, and if you're interested in contributing or have any questions, I'd be happy to collaborate.

- Documentation Page: https://nadobando.github.io/pydangorm
- Github Page: https://github.com/nadobando/pydangorm